# Windows Forms: How to setup a datagridview to use an inner join SQL Query?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want the Datagridview to display results based on a simple inner join.

I start by adding the gridview to the form, then configuring a data source. 
At this stage I can select the tables - all good. 
It then creates some non visual components on the form.

Now how do I get it to display results from the custom sql query I want to pass it?

Comment: You are wanting your gridview to only show results from the custom SQL query, correct? (When you selected the tables the first time I'd assume it selected all the columns and you are looking at displaying something more specific).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I'm going to go ahead and assume you want your gridview to display a custom sql query.

Step 1: Start by adding a DataSet.xsd to your project.

Step 2: Right click on the designer field and select "Add ---> Tableadapter". It will prompt you to connect to your datasource.

Step 3: On the third menu, select "Use SQL statements".

Step 4: Enter in the desired custom SQL query. Click "Next ---> Next --> Finish"

Step 5: Return to the gridview and click on the extended properties pane (that arrow in the upper right corner). Expand "Other Data Sources" ---> "Project Data Sources" --> DataSet --> and select the datatable you created no more than a minute ago.

[image]

This will allow you to display a custom SQL query in the gridview.

Let me know if you need any more clarification!

EDIT: Glad it worked out for you. If you wish to swap the code for dynamic grid functionality, right click on your datatable and add a new query. Then go locate the line in the form_load that takes care of the data population:

```
this.yourTableAdapter.Fill(this.yourDataSet.yourdatatable);
```

The default SQL query is always called .Fill, but in case you add a new query the second one will be called:

```
this.yourTableAdapter.FillBy(this.yourDataSet.yourdatatable);
```

By running this second method somewhere in your code (a button press maybe) the grid should change to the new sql command and display the new results.